# AngularJS - Getting Module constants from a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a myApp.config module to store some settings for my app, I wrote a config.js file:

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
    .constant('APP_NAME','My Angular App!')
    .constant('APP_VERSION','0.3');
```

I added it to my app.js (angular-seed):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.config']).
```

I added it to the index.html file, and now I'm trying to figure out how to get it in my controllers, I tried:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.config'])
  .controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'myApp.config', function($scope, $config) {
    $scope.printme = $config;
  }])
```

but I'm getting:

> Unknown provider: myApp.configProvider <- myApp.config

I'm probably doing something wrong here, any ideas ?

Comment: Asaf you tried to inject a module as a dependency in a controller, which will not work. A module can be a dependency of another module only.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I don't think it is valid to use the module name in an injection like that. You can simply inject the constants by name, though:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.config'])
  .controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'APP_NAME', function($scope, appName) {
     $scope.printme = appName;
}]);
```

Comment: Correct, there's one global dependency injection space, once you set up a `.constant` in any module you can inject the value anywhere else.

Comment: Is it generally a sensible way to have a config file (for customizable settings) in Angular?

Comment: @Asaf you can go with the following .constant service. `angular.module('app').constant('appSettings', { version: '1.0', appName: 'myApp'});`
Then inject it to a controller or .config or whatever you want like `angular.module('app').controller('simpleCtrl', ['appSettings', function(appSettings) { $scope.valueInIsolatedScope = appSettings.version; }])`

Answer (score 74):

I think the simplest approach is to add a constant using an object literal. This fits most application configuration use cases I think, because it supports a complex config object. The `constant` step also runs early, [before other providers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide) are registered.

```
angular.module('myApp').constant('cfg', {
  url: 'https://myapi.com/v1/',
  httpTimeout: 5000
})
```

To use it you just inject `cfg`:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('user', function(cfg, $http){
  // cfg and $http together at last
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have a constant provider with the key codes used for navigation and I would like to inject the constant provider to the controller (I want to avoid injecting each entry separately). Is that possible? I have some other services already injected.

Comment: Is it harder than: `angular.module('myApp').constant('keyCodes', { left: 36, right: 38 })'` and: `angular.module('myApp').factory('myComponent', function(keyCodes) { keyCodes.left })`?

Answer (score 5):

It should also be noted that SimplGy's solution means that the 'cfg' object is a constant, however the properties of that object are not. This means, that you cannot reassign 'cfg' like so:

```
cfg = { randomProperty: randomValue };
```

You CAN reassign the properties of the 'cfg' object like so:

```
cfg.url = 'BrandNewURL.com';
cfg.httpTimeout = 30;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Replies to other answers should be written as comments.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Apologies Ken. Unfortunately, I haven't gathered enough rep to comment yet, but I thought it was important for the author to be aware of the issues that can happen wen using Angulars 'Constant'.

Comment: @MattM I think you're fine.  Fitting all of that into a comment would have been impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the use of constants in this example:

```
angular
.module('abp001App', ['ngRoute'])
.constant("myConfig", {
    "url": "http://localhost",
    "port": "80"
})
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function (myConfig) {
    // Do something with myConfig...
});
```