# AngularJS + RequireJS + Feature oriented directory structure - how to use relative paths in templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, amd, angular-ui-router

I've seen a bunch of posts recommending using a directory per feature with angular. Today I've added RequireJS (AMD) to a new angular application I'm working on. I was using `script` tags at the end of the `body` tag, then I did some AMD restructuring and everything magically became 300% better.

It was all going great, the AMD style `require` supported relative paths when working with JS files, but with `templateUrl`, it starts at the root instead of in the directory I'm in. I've seen solutions like reading the "[currently executing script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103724/angular-directive-templateurl-relative-to-js-file)", I doubt that approach would work with AMD.

Is there a trick I don't know about to pass the path from somewhere? I don't mind doing some work per file, but I really don't want to do something like `templateUrl: baseUrl + 'template.view1.html'` everywhere I use `templateUrl`.

I'm using ui-router, if it matters (first day, yay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `require.toUrl(...)`

Take a look to the official docs: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes-urls

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this

```
angular.module('...', ['...'])
    .constant('basePath', 'app/path/to/something/')
```

and later

```
templateUrl: basePath + 'morePath/myFile.html',
```

Comment: The good thing is, that you can use dependency injection. That is not visible in my three line sample but for the interested reader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383611/angularjs-getting-module-constants-from-a-controller - and one side note: Of course it is also possible to use a factory and get a perhaps more dynamic value out of this. For me, the constant way worked smoothly.

Comment: I would have to remember to glue the base path to the relative path every time I use `templateUrl` *and* pass the path individually for each feature directory because I chose feature-oriented directory structure. I was hoping for something cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little project, [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/) trying to mix RequireJS and Angular. In it I have written the `templateCache` AMD plugin, working as:

```
require(['templateCache!./navbar.html',...], function(navbarTemplate, ...) {...});
```

So, the proper template is loaded (using RequireJS's `text!` plugin under the hoods - so it is compilable with r.js too). The object you get (the `navbarTemplate` argument in the example above) has 2 properties, one is the actual loaded text and one the URL, under which the text is registered with Angular's `templateCache`. You can then use it as:

```
require(['templateCache!./navbar.html',...], function(navbarTemplate, ...) {
    ...
    // will give you the correct URL, with `./` expanded properly
    // the text is already registered with Angular
    templateUrl: navbarTemplate.path
    ...
});
```

Unfortunately, I haven't gotten into making angular-require-lazy compatible with ui-router yet, so you cannot use it as is. The code of the plugin (really small) might give you some idea for your own implementation of this feature:

```
define(["module", "./currentModule"], function(module, currentModule) {
    "use strict";

    /** RequireJS module loader entry point. */
    function load(name, parentRequire, onload, config) {
        parentRequire(["text!" + name], function(t) {
            if( !config || !config.isBuild ) {
                currentModule.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
                    $templateCache.put(name, t);
                }]);
            }
            onload({
                text: t,
                path: name
            });
        });
    }

    return {
        load: load
    };
});
```

(The `currentModule` is angular-require-lazy - specific, you will have to replace at least that with the current Angular module.)

Comment: this is a good method but I was really hoping to avoid polluting the top of the file with all these requires for templates. I realize now I can just make it work with relative paths with the `text!` plugin (I didn't know about it until now, I just started using r.js)

Comment: Yes, revisiting your case it may be enough to require the `text!./file.html` and then use it as `template: file`.